# JavaScript library for logic programming

Tags: javascript, logic

Do you know of any good javascript library for logic programming?

I'm interested in something like [jsprolog](http://ioctl.org/logic/prolog-latest), but I want to use javascript to communicate with the lib, and not a different language (such as prolog in this case).

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at Python? It has a syntax very similar (IMO a bit more readable) than that language you linked to, and there are JS implementations of a subset of Python.

Comment: Not sure I have explained myself clearly enough. Extracting the meaning of what I tried to say: Desired paradigm: logic programming; Desired language: javascript; Desired syntax: javascript.

Comment: See this related discussion about JavaScript implementations of Prolog: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435462/prolog-systems-in-javascript

Comment: @try-catch-finally As far as I know, these operators do not provide [logic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming) features in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to jsprolog, there are several JavaScript libraries for logic programming:

- [chr.js](https://github.com/fnogatz/CHR.js) is a constraint logic programming library for JavaScript. It is an implementation of the [Constraint Handling Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_Handling_Rules) programming language.
- There are several [JavaScript implementations of Datalog](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&newwindow=1&biw=1280&bih=591&q=datalog+javascript&oq=datalog+javascript&gs_l=serp.3..35i39k1.10948.12832.0.13102.2.2.0.0.0.0.207.207.2-1.1.0....0...1.1.64.serp..1.1.207.qop7zll73MU) such as [DataScript](https://github.com/tonsky/datascript).
- [Yield Prolog](http://yieldprolog.sourceforge.net/) allows Prolog programs to be embedded directly in JavaScript. This is especially useful because it allows JavaScript functions to be used in Prolog predicates, and vice-versa.
- [LogicJS](https://github.com/mcsoto/LogicJS) is a JavaScript library that is based on [MiniKanRen](http://minikanren.org/), which has been implemented in many programming languages, including JavaScript.
- [JavaScript-Logic-Programming-System](https://github.com/IvanIvanov/JavaScript-Logic-Programming-System) is another logic programming system for JavaScript.
- There is [another Prolog implementation](https://curiosity-driven.org/prolog-interpreter) that was written in less than 200 lines of JavaScript code.

Of course, there are also several [C++ libraries for logic programming](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+logic+programming#newwindow=1&q=c%2B%2B+%22logic+programming%22) that could be automatically ported into JavaScript using [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten).

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of other languages that compile to javascript: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS

It is possible (although not probable!) one of those has a javascript friendly API AND a suitable library that can by "compiled" into JavaScript.

Exactly what you aren't looking for, and probably a time waster :)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this list. Not what I'm looking for. Thanks though.

Comment: Hopefully that link is useful to someone else coming to this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out (JSL) https://www.npmjs.com/package/lib-jsl.

From the overview document, JSL is a JSON based logic programming library meant for embedded use in JS programs. It uses JSON as its syntax as well as I/O method

Answer (score 1):

There is a new tool, a generic compiler adding any effect to JS, including logic programming, there is an example of prolog append: https://github.com/awto/mfjs-samples/tree/master/unify